# Dropping from Simulator on-device testing to Alpha tester

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm building an Action on Google and struggling to use the Alpha testers functionality. I have two G Suite accounts: one business and one personal (yes, I use G Suite, not Gmail for my family email). My business account is the Project Owner of the AoG project, and it's where I do most of my work. My Google Home is associated with my personal account, as is the Assistant app on my iPhone.

Initially for testing I added my personal account as a Project Owner and used the Simulator to enable Testing on Device. This allowed me to test my Action using my Google Home on my personal account.

Now I'd like to switch my personal account to be an Alpha tester, instead of using Testing on Device. While logged into the console on my personal account, I put the Simulator back into the state "No tests currently active." Somewhere along the way I whitelisted my personal account and opened the Opt-in link in a browser signed-in as my personal account. I clicked Send to Device -> Living Room Speaker (later I tried sending to my iPhone, too), but I still can't get to my Action. When I say "Talk to ", it responds with generic search results or the wrong Action.

How can I get my personal account back into a state where it can become an Alpha tester of my Action, after having used the Simulator's "Testing on Device" functionality in the past?

Comment: Did you published, with your G suite account, your application in alpha release? I didn't read it

Comment: Yes, my Action is published to Alpha by my business account, and the preview link renders fine for my personal account.